# Activate InstallShield 2012 LE (limited edition) on a Team Build machine

Tags: tfsbuild, installshield-le

As stated in the license agreement, "Flexera Software grants Licensee the right to install and use the software on a single computer to be used 
exclusively with Visual Studio and the right to install and use up to two (2) additional instances for use within a Team Foundation Server environment".

The latter is exactly what I did: i installed the InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition on a Team Build machine (Team Foundation System 2012), where no installations of Visual Studio exist.
Now, I can correctly compile and build my solution containing an ISL project. The problem is that when I run the built setup.exe, a message stating "This Setup was created with an EVALUATION VERSION of InstallShield" is shown.

So, the question is: **how can I activate InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition on a Team Build machine where Visual Studio hasn't been installed?**

Comment: Ask InstallShield Support.  That's not really a development question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the License Activation on your TFS Build Server.

for the spring 2012 edition of Installshield LE the activator program can be found at C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\System\TSConfig.exe

this will bring up a dialog box, and you can enter your activation code they sent when you registered for the InstallShield LE.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the "Standalone Build" on your TFS build server? A license file (.lic) is required to install the Standalone Build. It can be obtained from the Product & License Center at https://flexerasoftware.subscribenet.com .

During installation of the standalone build, it should ask you for the .lic file. If you didn't have one at install time, it would create a trial install.

Comment: As I read it, users of InstallShield LE do not have access to a "Standalone Build" license. I ran into [other issues](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?198431-Standadlone-build-error-with-MSBUILD), so I just disabled InstallShield projects for my TFS build for now ...